# Logstash grok plugin, add field when matched

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a grok match like this:

```
grok{ match => [ “message”, “Duration: %{NUMBER:duration}”, “Speed: %{NUMBER:speed}” ] }
```

I also want to add another field to captured variables if it matches a grok pattern. I know I can use mutate plugin and if-else to add new fields but I have too many matches and it will be too long that way. As an example, I want to capture right-side fields for given texts.

```
"Duration: 12" => [duration: "12", type: "duration_type"]
"Speed: 12" => [speed: "12", type: "speed_type"]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if that is what you need, but I did something similar. I have a basic parsing for my message, and then I analyse a specific field additionally with optional matches.

```
grok {
            break_on_match => false
            patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns"
            match => {
                "message" => "\[%{LOGLEVEL:level}\] \[%{IPORHOST:from}\] %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{DATA:thread}\] \[%{NOTSPACE:logger}\] %{GREEDYDATA:msg}"
                "thread" => "(%{GREEDYDATA}%{REQUEST_TYPE:reqType}%{SPACE}%{URIPATH:reqPath}(%{URIPARAM:reqParam})?)?"
            }
        }
```

As you can see, the first one simply matches the complete message. I have a field thread, that is basically the Logger information. However, in my setup, http requests append some info to the thread name. In these cases, I want to OPTIONALLY match these as well.

Wit the above setup, the fields reqType, reqPath, reqParam are only created, if thread can match them. Otherwise they aren't.

I hope this is what you wanted.

Thanks,
Artur

Comment: Not exactly what I asked, but helps with my current problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
filter{
  grok { match =>  [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:types}: %{NUMBER:value}" ] }
  mutate {
    lowercase => [ "types" ]
    add_field => { "%{types}" => "%{value}"
                   "type" => "%{types}_type" }
    remove_field => [ "value", "types" ]
  }
}
```